# How can i draw multiple random variables from multiple arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, struct, blackjack

I am very new to c++ and really, programming in general. To learn how to use the language, I am trying to create a very simple game of blackjack.

I currently have the code below, that defines what a card is and adds the variables needed for one before introducing some arrays that define the possibilities for those variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


struct DefineCard {

    char cardSuit;
    int cardFace;
    int cardValue;
    int cardStatus;

} Deck[53];

int main()
{   
    
    string cardSuits[4] = { "clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds" };
    string cardFaces[13] = { "ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king" };
    string cardStatus[3] = { "in play", "in deck", "discarded" };
    int cardValue[13] = { 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };

}
```

From this code, assuming I have it correct, how would I draw a random card containing all these variables randomly and then ensure that the same card is not drawn twice?

Thanks for all the help, and sorry for any blatant misunderstandings on my part, I'm very new to this :)

Comment: Put your 52 cards in a std::vector and use std::shuffle to shuffle the deck. Then deck[0] is the next card to pick.

Comment: Ace value is 11... or 1

Answer (score 2):

I assume you could do something like this:

Do what drescherjm said in their comment (get each unique card into a `std::vector` deck, then `std::shuffle` it up, optionally).

Also, consider changing the type of `cardFace` and `cardStatus` to `std::string`, which is how they're represented (unless I'm missing something).

Here's my naïve idea for building and shuffling a deck of cards, using your `DefineCard` struct:

```
std::vector<DefineCard> deck;
    
// iterate through the four card suits
for (int i{ 0 }; i < 4; ++i)
{
    // iterate through the thirteen card values and faces
    for (int j{ 0 }; j < 13; ++j)
    {
        // all cards start "in deck"; need to static_cast ""in deck"" to string because it's currently a string literal (const char*, not std::string)
        DefineCard card{ cardSuits[i], cardFaces[j], cardValue[j], static_cast<string>("in deck") };
        // add the new card to the end of the vector (same as append() in Python)
        deck.push_back(card);
    }            
}

// shuffle the deck randomly (need to #include <random> for std::shuffle() and #include <chrono> to get a seed value)
std::shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end(), std::default_random_engine(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()));
```

Comment: i strongly endorse this answer